# Axios: Invalid character in header content ['adapter']

Tags: typescript, axios

Here's a sample code to show the issue:

```
import axios, {  AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

function mergeRequestParams(defaultParams: AxiosRequestConfig, params1: AxiosRequestConfig, params2?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig {
  return {
    ...defaultParams,
    ...params1,
    ...(params2 || {}),
    headers: {
      ...defaultParams,
      ...(params1.headers || {}),
      ...((params2 && params2.headers) || {}),
    },
  };
}

(async () => {
  try {

    const client = axios.create({

      transformRequest: [(data, headers) => { return data; }],   // Without this I get: Invalid character in header content ["transformRequest"] 
      transformResponse: [(data, headers) => { return data; }], // Without this I get: Invalid character in header content ["transformResponse"] 

      baseURL: "https://localhost:7001/",
    });

    const requestParams = mergeRequestParams(client.defaults, {}, {})

    client.request({
      ...requestParams,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        ...requestParams.headers,
      },
      params: {date:'2020-03-31'},
      responseType: 'json',
      url: '/overview',
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log( e);
  }
})();
```

The error I get here is:

```
(node:60845) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["adapter"]
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:529:3)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:241:14)
    at Object.request (https.js:314:10)
    at RedirectableRequest._performRequest (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:262:24)
    at new RedirectableRequest (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:60:8)
    at Object.request (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:458:14)
    at dispatchHttpRequest (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:195:25)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at httpAdapter (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:46:10)
    at dispatchRequest (/Users/kamz/workspace/clarity/clarity-model/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
(node:60845) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:60845) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `mergeRequestParams` function.  Inside the `headers` you need to spread `...defaultParams.headers` instead of `...defaultParams`.

It's actually ok to spread `undefined` so you can simplify the code to:

```
function mergeRequestParams(defaultParams: AxiosRequestConfig, params1: AxiosRequestConfig, params2?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig {
  return {
    ...defaultParams,
    ...params1,
    ...params2,
    headers: {
      ...defaultParams.headers,
      ...params1.headers,
      ...params2?.headers,
    },
  };
}
```

Though I personally think it would be better to define a function that combines two configs and use that as a callback for `Array.reduce` to combine any number of configs.

```
function mergeTwoParams(params1: AxiosRequestConfig, params2: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig {
  return {
    ...params1,
    ...params2,
    headers: {
      ...params1.headers,
      ...params2.headers,
    },
  };
}

function mergeRequestParams(...params: AxiosRequestConfig[]): AxiosRequestConfig {
  return params.reduce(mergeTwoParams, {}); // initial value is only needed to prevent error when calling with 0 configs
}
```